# Windows XP Scheduler - Error Adding Another Task (data area passed to a system call is too small)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduler, task

I'm getting an error "data area passed to a system call is too small" when trying to add a task to the Windows Scheduler. We currently have about 20 tasks in it.

Googling the issue, we found to stop/start the task service, wait, and some kind of clean-up would be run. We've done this multiple times and it's not fixing anything. Even if we delete a task, we can not re-add one.

Has anyone seen this problem and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[Task Scheduler returns a "HRESULT: 0x8007007A" error message after you save many jobs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264522):

> To work around this behavior, stop and start the task scheduler
>   service, **wait for 10 to 15 minutes**, and then schedule jobs.
>
> There is a scavenger tool in task scheduler that **runs 10 minutes after
>   the service is started.** This tool frees the memory that is still being
>   used by deleted or scheduled jobs.

How long did you wait?

Alternatively, try to delete the following reg key:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\UserKeys\Schedule
```

Comment: 10, 20, 30, and 60 minutes. This does not fix the problem for me.

Comment: have you checked to see if you've got any tasks running against a user/program that doesnt exist anymore? If you have, delete it!

Comment: @G Yes, we've removed all tasks that aren't needed. There's got to be something else that's wrong. We're only talking about 20 tasks or less that are currently set up.